# Pinescript: Plots extending to next day

Tags: pine-script-v5

My plot is getting extended beyond trading hours.
how do I plot and limit to today's eod time?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jokr1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session{dot}ismarket](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dismarket)

```
plot(session.ismarket ? .... : na, ....)
```